# How can I sum up values within Google Sheet cells under a specific condition?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to create a Google Sheet that automatically sums up some values. For each green tick in a `Present?` cell $15 should be added to `Total Sum`, for each red x nothing should be added. So that all I have to do is fill in presence and the total sum will be calculated.

| Date | Present? | money added | Total Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/21 | ✅ | + $15 | $15 |
| 1/2/21 | ❌ | + $0 | $15 |
| 1/3/21 | ✅ | + $15 | $30 |
| 1/4/21 | ❌ | + $0 | $30 |
| ... | .... | ... | ... |
| 2/24/21 | ❌ | + $0 | $300 (example) |

My idea: I need some if condition like `=IF( *Present cell* is ✅, then *money added cell* is $15, if not then *money added cell* is 0)` and for `Total Sum` I just need to build the Sum over the whole `money added` column to get the interim values up until the present date.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that `Date` is column `A`, that `Present?` is column `B` etc.

Cell `D2` would be:

```
=IF(B2 = "✅", C2, 0)
```

And cell `D3` would be:

```
=IF(B3 = "✅", D2+C3, D2)
```

Repeat `D3` until bottom of dataset.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifHYkD4zUVQ17uFQl7MZd2sZfx8swCYMZ2blVX8jwfQ/edit?usp=sharing).